# Chat application using socket.io in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

**"Could not install package 'SocketIO4Net.Client 0.6.26'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1"**.Getting this error while installing the library..Please help me to find an appropriate library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message means that you try to install a library that is not compatible with Windows Phone 8.1.

Lookat that nuget package shows only a .net 4.0 library:

```
socketio4net.client.0.6.26\lib\net40
```

which can be only used in Desktop .Net 4.x (40, 4.5.x, 4.6.x) projects.

You need to use a WinRT compatible lib that supports Phone 8.1.